# Delete remotely oracle schema using shell script

Tags: shell-script, sql, oracle-database

I have a **remote instance** like **database-ora12** with existing user tester / password and SID=orac

How I can delete remotely database or schema from this system for this user using shell script without SQLPlus.

Adding more details:

- Instances from where shell script executed = hcuser, bkuser
- Oracle Instance on which oracle db exists = database-ora12
- Oracle username = tester for hcuser / btester for bkuser
- Oracle password = password
- SID = orac

As mention above, a script uses to delete or drop the schema on oracle instance from different shell instances.

Comment: Why can't you use sqlplus? What have you tried so far and what was the result?

Comment: I've removed the [tag:sqlite] tag because it's got no relevance whatsoever to an Oracle database. I've also changed [tag:oracle] to [tag:oracle-database].

Comment: @Jeff: currently the system administerator don't want to install sqlplus on linux systems where script will going to execute.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use SQL*Plus, you are going to find it tricky to perform any database schema operations from a shell script.

You could write a Pro*C application (or something equivalent), use Perl's `DBI` and `DBD::Oracle` modules, or the equivalent in a language such as Python or PHP.